# Chat flutuante na página

Tags: javascript

Basicamente, eu gostaria de um chat flutuante na página como esse:

O código do chatbox é:

```
<script style="width: 170px;height: 276px;" src="//st.chatango.com/js/gz/emb.js" async="" data-cfasync="false" id="cid0020000093941551878">{"handle":"bloodypalacerpg","arch":"js","styles":{"a":"CC0000","b":100,"c":"FFFFFF","d":"FFFFFF","k":"CC0000","l":"CC0000","m":"CC0000","n":"FFFFFF","p":"11.25","q":"CC0000","r":100,"usricon":1.3,"cnrs":"0.89","fwtickm":1}}</script>
```

Como eu desejo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Ele é fixo ou segue o scroll? pode arrastar ou não?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu podes resolver isso usando CSS.
Com `position:fixed;` Assim ele sempre fica visível, mesmo rolando a tela.

Comment: Muito obrigado! ^^ Funcionou.

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: absolute`.

```
#chat{
   width: 300px;
   height: 300px;
   position: absolute;
   right: 20px;
   bottom: 20px;
}
```